# Yesod Database Query

Tags: database, haskell, yesod

I'm new to both Yesod and Databases so please bear with me this basic question:

I plan to write SQL procedures and store them in .sql files and the Yesod web application just calls these sql file instead of writing queries directly in Haskell.

Is this common practice?

I assume that writing queries in SQL itself is more suitable than writing them in Haskell.

Any comments are welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is this common practice?

No. The closest you can get to this is use something like [rawSql](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-8.8/persistent-2.6.1/Database-Persist-Sql.html#v:rawSql) in persistent or use some other low level library. I would recommend you to avoid writing raw sql query unless you have a valid reason to.

> I assume that writing queries in SQL itself is more suitable than writing them in Haskell.

No, the whole point of using [persistent](http://www.yesodweb.com/book/persistent) is to bring type safety to database queries. If you are gonna write them in SQL itself you lose that benefit.

Comment: depending on what "sql" you are using - there is also [opaleye](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/opaleye)